# how to reduce the size of a dataframe?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to read multiple csv files from a directory by the following code, but it changes the size of each dataframe from 150000 to 150001, which causes problem when I test it with my trained dataset output which is of 150000 size. any body can fix this? since I'm a complete beginner to ML multiple suggestions and (explanation) would be appreciated... Note that dataFrame.iloc() did not worked in this scenario.

```
# indir = ".//test"
# os.chdir(indir)
fileList = glb.glob("*.csv")
# dfList = []
for filenames in fileList:
  print(filenames)
  df = pd.read_csv(filenames, header=None`
  df[0][0] = 0
  df.iloc[0:]
  print(df.size) 
#   dfList.append(df)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with  `df[0][0] = 0` and  `df.iloc[0:]` Just remove them and append to your list normally?

Comment: Is the first row of every CSV the names of the columns?

Comment: set header to 1

Comment: @pythonic833 I think you mean set header to 0

Comment: why 0? i thought the problem is that there is one line too much in the dataframe. I suppose this is the header, so set it to 1 to use it as header and not to have it as part of the df

Comment: yes, first row of each csv is column names, that's why I'm using df[0][0] = 0 and df.iloc[0:] I added after getting the error to reduce the size of dataframe which did not work

Comment: Change `df = pd.read_csv(filenames, header=None)` to `df = pd.read_csv(filenames)`. You are including your header row in the body of your dataframe which is why it is 1 row larger than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Why will you put `header = None`. If you already know that the first row of the csv file is the column names, then put `header = 0` which will tell pandas to read the first row as the header and not a row. This will result in correct size.

Also with your code, you are not dropping the first row, hence it is wrong. To drop the first row, you have to use `df = df.iloc[1:]`

Comment: Thanks everyone the header thing solves the problem, which was pretty obvious but somehow I had not consider it at the first place .